# Minimum of last k

Tags: code-golf, number, restricted-complexity

Write a function that takes two arguments: a number `k` and a list `l`, and that returns another list `r` such that `r[i] = min(l[i-k+1:i])`.

### Examples

- **Input** k=2, l=1,2,3,4,5,6
- **Ouput** r=1,1,2,3,4,5
- **Input** k=3, l=-1,9,7,-9,8,3,5,0,12,1,2,3,-1,-2,-3
- **Ouput** r=-1,-1,-1,-9,-9,-9,3,0,0,0,1,1,-1,-2,-3

Constraints: **O(len(l))** time complexity. *Shortest code* wins.

Comment: Please use the `code-golf` tag when asking for shortest code.

Comment: Why the complexity contraint if the goal is shortest code?

Comment: I don't really understand the formula after sucht that..., can you explain it further to me?

Comment: @FUZxxl: r[i] is minimum of the last k elements in l ending at i.

Comment: This task is probably as complex as a sort, so O(len(l)) can be obtained

Comment: Is the function allowed to just modify the original array, or does it need to return a new one?

Comment: Are arrays 0-indexed or 1-indexed? Also what does `a[i:j]` mean? You should clarify the semantics of the code.

Comment: Seemed `j` represents number of items to take, starting with `i`. But if `i` is non-positive, then `i` is 1 (if 1-indexed), as in [this](https://tio.run/##VU29DoIwEN55ioZoCnK1tohCsCuJi74ACwGJBIMEShzEZ8cWCNG7W@77zZL2PgxpIvv2liHc0u1GIkrx9F7ClsYVjQ2kR6FpJxFJfdInrxKRCBB@58/GKgQLi5O4RKFdN0Ulc3PNM2TCyiocxw5HzDQ/eBh0zrmqVUwpOKCHYMDBhT14cBhbrp0mG4UvjPFrcrWJMAjgCCQAX0k82AHjs15RhANx/8I0OF0wn6s8enXNYvkC)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## R, 75 bytes

```
f=function(k,l){r=l;for(i in 1:length(l));r[i]=min(l[max(1,(i-k+1)):i]);r}
```

Testing:

```
f(3, c(-1,9,7,-9,8,3,5,0,12,1,2,3,-1,-2,-3))
[1] -1 -1 -1 -9 -9 -9  3  0  0  0  1  1 -1 -2 -3

f(2, 1:6)
[1] 1 1 2 3 4 5
```

Not sure how to calculate the complexity of this.

Comment: Complexity is O(N*K)

Comment: I think you can remove the `;` in `length(l));r[i]`

Answer (score 1):

## SmileBASIC, 97 bytes

```
DEF M(K,L)DIM T[0],R[0]FOR I=1TO LEN(L)COPY T,L,MAX(I,K)-K,MIN(I,K)PUSH R,MIN(T)NEXT
RETURN R
END
```

Explanation:
This line uses `COPY dest[],source[],start,length` to get part of the list into a temporary array:

```
COPY TEMP,LIST,MAX(I-K,0),MIN(I,K)
```

Example for a list of size 6, with K=3

```
I|start|length
1| 0   | 1
2| 0   | 2
3| 0   | 3
4| 1   | 3
5| 2   | 3
6| 3   | 3
```

Answer (score 1):

## K, 32 bytes

`{|&/',/+((x*!_(#y)%x)+/:!x)_\:|y}`

Translating the symbols to meaning, that is:
reverse min over each flattened transpose (firstargument multipliedby enumerate truncate (countof secondargument) dividedby firstargument)add eachright enumerate first argument) cutby eachleft reverse secondargument

It's not as terse as J, as K is a simpler language, but it is still interesting

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! We actually don't require "non-competing" anymore. Our policy has changed in the last year. You may answer using any language you want.

Answer (score 0):

I come from the future (from [this future](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/113915/suggest-me-a-challenge)) and, since I'm learning J, I thought I'd give it a try.

## J, 21 bytes (non-competing)

```
<./"1@([,\$&_@<:@[,])
```

It prefixes the list with (K - 1) infinities, partitions it in overlapping chunks of length K and then computes the minimum of those. That's O(K*len(L)) if I'm not mistaken but, AFAICT, you need stateful computation to achieve O(len(L)) which isn't very idiomatic in J.

#### Usage:

```
   2 <./"1@([,\$&_@<:@[,]) 1 2 3 4 5 6
1 1 2 3 4 5

   3 <./"1@([,\$&_@<:@[,]) _1 9 7 _9 8 3 5 0 12 1 2 3 _1 _2 _3
_1 _1 _1 _9 _9 _9 3 0 0 0 1 1 _1 _2 _3
```

Answer (score 0):

### Matlab, 72 bytes

```
function[r]=f(k,l),for i=1:length(l),r(i)=min(l(max(1,i-k+1):i));end;end
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##FYlBDsIgFAWv4vITH4kfYrRtOEnTRVNBf0ohIWi8PeJiFjOTt7p@fGvhnbYqOc1lcYF2RIWQy0kcj9GnZ31RL4VEuUMSRTrWLzFE72dWoyg1@fT40wJZzJox4AY94A6LKy5gA4bp0pc20HZR7Qc)

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 92 bytes

This is a [restricted-complexity](/questions/tagged/restricted-complexity) question asking specifically for a program that runs in O(len(l)) time, yet all the other answers in 7½ years have ignored that constraint.  Here’s one that satisfies it.

```hs
g id
g _ _[]=[]
g h k l|(a,b)<-splitAt(k-1)l=h(scanl1 min a)++g(zipWith min$scanr1 min a)k b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TctBC4IwHAXwu5/if@iw4X/QNCshD9EX8FZgIktzG04T3Sn67K1JBN0e7/eeEnN3N8a12dVJ0E0goYKqKLOi9FFBB@ZFBN7ogc2j0fZoScc4NZkicy0Gw6HXAwgahpI89XjWVi3NasHphx3cXC98zKB5BADjpAcLpIUICo4RxrjBBLcl/bcYCsYxxR2yFPd@k@AaeYTfgycWIYtL6t51a4ScHbuc8vwD)

#### How it works

Split the list into blocks of *k* − 1.  Within each block, compute all prefix minima (with a left-to-right scan) and all suffix minima (with a right-to-left scan).  Then any sublist of *k* numbers crosses exactly one block boundary, and can therefore be computed as the minimum of a suffix minimum from the first block and a prefix minimum from the second block.