# Suggest me a challenge!

Tags: code-golf, stack-exchange-api

I am too bored and want a challenge to solve. But I do not see any interesting challenges, and I am too lazy to search for one. Can you (Well, technically your code) suggest me one?

---

## I/O

**Input:** None.

**Output:** A link to a random open(i.e. non-closed) challenge("Challenge" excludes [tips](/questions/tagged/tips)!) on PPCG. You may not link to an answer in a challenge, Just a challenge. (I didn't ask for an interesting answer!)

---

## Examples

**Valid:**

```
http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/93288/make-me-a-mooncake
http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/113796/raise-a-single-number
http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/113898
```

**Invalid:**

```
http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/78152/tips-for-golfing-in-matl (tips question)
http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/113896/josephus-problem (closed)
http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/84260/add-two-numbers/84365#84365 (linked to answer)
```

Comment: Can we output `http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/93288/` instead of `http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/93288/make-me-a-mooncake` (note the lack of challenge name).

Comment: @Kritixi Lithos Sure, that works.

Comment: Not all tips questions have the word "tips" in their name. See [this one](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/59238/golfing-strings) for example. Is that allowed or did you mean to remove challenges in the "tips" tag?

Comment: @seshoumara The latter, that's also the reason I typed 'tips' as a tag.

Comment: There are about 6k questions fulfilling your criteria on PPCG. Do all need to have a chance of being picked by random, or can I pick at random from the first 50 results I get from a search link?

Comment: @seshoumara the former option.

Comment: @SIGSEGV I believe there is no way to choose a random question from *every* open question asked.

Comment: @Okx Use your brain.. (Hint: every question and answer has an unique id)

Comment: Thanks. Also, can we only give [tag:code-golf] questions? The SE API needs either a tagged parameter or an intitle parameter.

Comment: @Okx Huh? I do not understand what you mean. I believe you can put newlines in code-golf too.

Comment: @SIGSEGV I mean questions with the tag [tag:code-golf]

Comment: @Okx you could generate the post id first, then see if it's valid. That way your problem is solved.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56087/discussion-between-okx-and-sigsegv).

Comment: I am going to answer with SEDE!

Comment: @DownChristopher Sure, Why not!

Comment: Actually one problem is it won't be a url but a id for the question. Would that be invalid? (I think so)

Comment: These people who don't answer all latest questions, and then say they're bored... Did you write an answer for every new question posted? You seem to only have written 17 answers.

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 209 bytes

Does work, but will most likely hit the StackExchange API limit very quickly. It will probably take a while to output the link, as it's checking randomly for a valid question.

```
_=>fetch(`//api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/${new Date%2e4}?site=codegolf`).then(_=>_.json()).then((a,b=a.items)=>{if(!b.length||b[0].tags.includes`tips`||b[0].closed_date)f();else console.log(b[0].link)})
```

```js
f=_=>fetch(`//api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/${new Date%2e4}?site=codegolf`).then(_=>_.json()).then((a,b=a.items)=>{if(!b.length||b[0].tags.includes`tips`||b[0].closed_date)f();else console.log(b[0].link)})

f();
```

Comment: The OP said that all questions fitting the requirements need to have a chance of being chosen at random.

Comment: @seshoumara should be fixed now.

Comment: Save 4 bytes by dropping the API version from the URL.

Comment: Got https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/173/tips-for-code-golfing-in-c which is not valid

Comment: Can confirm that this generates [tag:tips] challenges too...

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, <s>452</s> 339 bytes

```
from requests import*
from random import*
while 1:
    n=randrange(999999)
    r=get("http://api.stackexchange.com/questions/%d?site=codegolf"%n).json()
    if r["items"]:
        m=r["items"][0]
        if "tips" not in m["tags"]:
            try:m["closed_date"]
            except:print("http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/%d"%n);break
```

A bit unsightly and not very golf-y, but I couldn't figure out a better way to do it. Since this more or less brute-forces the API, you'll spend up your quota quite quickly and start getting errors, but after a few hours it'll work again.

EDIT: Saved 113 bytes by removing multiple unnecessary things, thanks to NoOneIsHere.

Comment: You only use `l` once, so it is unnecessary.

Comment: That's correct. I did that so I could print the link afterwards if it was valid, but that printed the API link instead of the normal one. Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: Also, you can online the `try` and maybe the `except`.

Comment: That is also correct. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad to help.  Pad

Answer (score 1):

## SEDE SQL: 79 bytes

```
Select Id from posts where ClosedDate IS NULL AND Tags !='tips' ORDER BY RAND()
```

There are 2 catches. One you have to wait for a while before running again or you have a cache hit (as a mod told me) and you only get the question id number.

Comment: I think it is valid because I am not that lazy to not even being able to type

Comment: Yes! Your word is lay on your challenge